# excel vba select last row and last column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select from `A9` to the `lastrow & lastcolumn`.

I have this to select the last cell, but it doesn't select from `A9 to Last` it just selects the lastrow/lastcolumn. Also this is not ideal because if I have blanks in the future.

I have searched and could not find anything for selecting from a cell to the `lastrow & lastcolumn`

```
Sub FindLast()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("A9").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Search order in my file would be Column `A` & Row `8` if that helps at all.

> Code Below is what I am using to work on active sheets

```
Sub SelectAll()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WholeRng As Range

With ActiveWorksheet
    Set Rng = Cells

    'last row
    lastRow = Rng.Find(What:="*", After:=Rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

    'last column
    lastCol = Rng.Find(What:="*", After:=Rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

    Set WholeRng = Range(Cells(9, "A"), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    WholeRng.Select
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: First, you probably don't want to actually `Select it, please see [How to Avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). Also, where have you searched? What have you tried? This question has been asked many times (see "related" posts to the right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could exploit UsedRange

```
Sub FindLast()
    With Activesheet
        .Range(.Range("A9"), .UsedRange.Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The safest way is use the `Find` function:

```
Option Explicit  

Sub LastRow_Col_Find()

    ' Safest way to ensure you got the last row:
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WholeRng As Range

    With Worksheets("report")   
        Set Rng = .Cells
        ' Safest way to ensure you got the last row
        lastRow = Rng.Find(What:="*", After:=Rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
        'MsgBox lastRow ' <-- for DEBUG

        ' Safest way to ensure you got the last column            
        lastCol = Rng.Find(What:="*", After:=Rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
        'MsgBox lastColumn ' <-- for DEBUG

        ' set the Range for the entire UsedRange in "YourSheetName" sheet
        Set WholeRng = .Range(.Cells(9, "A"), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
        WholeRng.Select '<-- ONLY IF YOU MUST
    End With
End Sub
```